# Ubuntu 22.04 iso too big for DVD

Tags: live-usb, lts, dvd

I am trying to install ubuntu-22.04-2-desktop-amd64.iso on an HP Z210 computer. When I go into the BIOS boot menu with a bootable USB inserted, the BIOS does not recognize the USB stick. So I need to burn the iso to a DVD but at 4.9 GB it is too big to fit. I don't have any dual-sided DVD drives. I mounted and browsed the iso but don't see anything that I could delete like foreign language support.

Does anybody have a method to reduce the size of the ISO to fit on a 4.7 GB DVD disk?

Comment: This is a known problem with the ISOs, and unfortunately they are already compressed down to this size with maximum compression.  There is unfortunately no way to compress the standard Ubuntu 22.04.2 image down smaller without changing key components of the ISO which will make the ISO's self-verify steps fail.

Comment: You could use the Ubuntu 22.04.1 ISO at 3.8GB, or drop back to Lubuntu for a smaller ISO. Updates and the hwe packages will bring you up to date.

Comment: 1. If it would be OK for you to install an Ubuntu community flavour (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) with a different (and lighter) desktop environment, there is still enough drive space on a DVD disk; 2. Another alternative is to install Ubuntu Server, and when booted into it install the Ubuntu Desktop via its meta-package: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: It might also be possible to boot via **plop** (which is a very small system) on a CD or DVD disk and let it transfer the boot process to a USB drive with Ubuntu. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB#PLoP_Boot_Manager).

Comment: If older system, you may not want Ubuntu but a lighter weight flavor. Full Ubuntu works best with newer systems. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie But even older systems boot from USB flash drives which then are reusable. I burned so many bad DVDs that I stopped using DVDs years ago. I use Kubuntu which is more of a mid-weight flavor but can work on many older systems.

Comment: Thank you all for the informative answers. I'm planning to install MythTV on this system (it's running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with MythTV on a different partition now), so I'll probably install 22.04.1 and update from there. Not sure how to mark this SOLVED. Do I Edit my post to update the subject?

Comment: You don't mark [solved] as in the Ubuntu Forums. Instead, if there is a formal answer, that solves your problem, accept it (click a tick icon), but there is not yet any answer, only comments. So unless there will be an answer, you can solve your problem, and write an own answer, where you describe your method and result and then (maybe after 2 days) you can accept it (click the tick icon). It will help others who look for a solution of the same or a similar problem.

Comment: I checked mythtv.org and decided that my best solution in this case is to use xubuntu, since I do most of my work on my Dell Precision laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I want the mythtv box to easily do other things than just myth but I don't need a full-up Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Sudodus, I don't see a tick icon, just the flag and edit icons or Answer Your Question.

Comment: The tick mark is only beside answers, not questions. The best thing to do here if the commenters don't wish to write an answer is for you to post what helped you as a answer. Then in a day or so come back and accept it. A bit clumsy but that's how it works.

Comment: @MarkP, I think you have found a good solution now. - But for the future, you could make a plop CD or DVD disk and test that method, because then it should be possible to boot from USB (and you can re-use a USB pendrive for several new systems via the same plop disk).

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody have a method to reduce the size of the ISO to fit on a 4.7 GB DVD disk?

Not really. You could download the ISO, mount it using squash-fs and then remove packages, recreate the ISO. It is a lot of work and there are better options. 2 of them:

1. use the server ISO and use `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to install Ubuntu. There are more DE's you can install if you do not want gnome3.
2. download the ISO and boot from it from GRUB. You can add the ISO to the GRUB boot options and pick it from there. Here is an [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1319274/15811)

Slightly altered to remove the version:

```
menuentry 'UbuntuCustom3' {
  set root='hd0,5'
  set isofile=/ubuntu.iso
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/install/vmlinuz boot=install iso-scan/filename="${isofile}" noprompt noeject
  initrd (loop)/install/initrd.gz
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to compress the Ubuntu ISO image, because it is already compressed unto its extremity.

You could install some other Ubuntu Flavor, which has a desktop that is less in size then Ubuntu's (Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu).

Comment: not on askUBUNTU.... why not answer with: use the server ISO and install a desktop afterwards? would make it ontopic :P

Comment: AskUbuntu covers several Ubu' derivatives including Xubuntu, Lubuntu, and Kubuntu, fwiw. See the [help pages](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for a longer list.