# Ubuntu 22.04 bootable DVD in English

Tags: 22.04

Where can I find Ubuntu 22.04 on a bootable DVD in Germany but with the possibility of installing (individual installation) in English

Comment: Welcome. "Bootable DVD's" are deprecated as an installation media. Today, everybody installs from USB sticks or over network.

Comment: Ubuntu installers are multilanguage but they haven't sent out physical disks in over a decade. You could download an ISO, and get someone with a DVD writer to burn it for you? USB installs are a lot better though for all sorts of reasons

Comment: Download it from the official site  https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop  Then create your installation media and follow the installation instructions.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no, because the latest releases are [too big for single-layer DVDs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470637/ubuntu-22-04-iso-too-big-for-dvd). So unless you have a double-layer DVD writer (I think they had a rather short lifetime), you're out of luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)